# Eclipse fails to launch on macOS Sierra

Tags: eclipse, cocoa, macos-sierra

I am having an issue with launching Eclipse on my macOS. Out of nowhere, the application fails to even launch. I navigated through terminal to the directory where the loader file is located (`/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS`) and executed the file using `./eclipse` which returned the following error.

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /Users/Viswanath/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.7.0.20160603-1933.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://463.fwk46259342:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [bundleresource://463.fwk46259342:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
```

What does the error signify? The application failed to launch in the safe boot mode as well. I further tried deleting existing Eclipse MARS installation, and installed Eclipse Neon which showed the same behavior. Any help on this issue is appreciated.

OS: macOS Sierra
Device: MacBook Air

Thank you,

Viswanath.

---

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: Can you check if you have java installed and if what version. Check if a java_home property is set ?